# PHP not recognized on Windows

Tags: php, windows, dos

I am trying to install symfony php framework.

I am working with windows.

My apache & php stuff is under `C:\wamp`

The framework is under `C:\dev\`

I am trying to do something like this in ms-dos:

```
c:\> php lib\vendor\symfony\data\bin\symfony -V
```

The php command isnt recognized. I suppose this is a pretty simple issue, but I have looked around without finding an answer anywhere.

Thanks,
Marius

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like directory in which `php.exe` is not in the `PATH` env variable. You have 2 options:

add that directory to `PATH` or

use complete path in your invocation as:

```
c:\> wamp\php\php.exe lib\vendor\symfony\data\bin\symfony -V
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the php directory to the PATH variable.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like PHP isnt on your path.  Try

```
c:\> path\to\php lib\vendor\....
```